# Not able to setup react project using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

Below is the error I am getting after running the command

```html
C:\Users\parde>npx create-react-app app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\parde\app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcore: 10552:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\parde\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-09T13_12_40_326Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting app/ from C:\Users\parde
Done.C:\Users\parde>npx create-react-app app
```

I tried:

1. Run npm cache clean --force
2. Then Run npx create-react-app (project name)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a network-related error. Have a look at this [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3815).
Try any of the following:

1. use a VPN
2. allow NodeJs in the firewall
3. update your npm `npm install --location=global`
4. reinstall NodeJs

Answer (score 0):

Theirs an issue related to it in the NPM repo
Seen to be something about the windows defender firewall

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3815